# При выборе параметра подгружаются значения

Tags: ajax, php

Нужно сделать так как на insales.com - http://gruzimfile.ru/file/257

Реализовал так - http://gruzimfile.ru/file/258
Но данные подгружаются только к первому параметру.

Код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getXmlHttpRequest(){
try {
    return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (ee) {
    }
}
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
}
function addListCity(text, id, i)
{
    if (text.length == 0 || !id) return;
    var option_textSel = document.getElementById("option_text");
    option_textSel.options[i] = new Option(text, id);
}
function showOption_text(option_text)
{
            var req = getXmlHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (req.readyState != 4) return;
                    var selcity = document.getElementById("seloption_text");
                    selcity.style.display = "block";
                    var sel = document.getElementById("option_text");
                    while (sel.hasChildNodes())
                        sel.removeChild(sel.lastChild);
                    var option_text = eval(req.responseText);
                    for (var i = 0; i < option_text.length; i++)
                        addListCity(option_text[i].name, option_text[i].id, i);
                }

            req.open("GET", "products_option.php?option=" + option_text, true);
            req.send(null);

}

</script>

//параметры
$reqoptions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products_options_name` ORDER BY `realid`");
while ($rowoptions = mysql_fetch_assoc($reqoptions))
{
$arrayrow_options[] = $rowoptions;
$smarty->assign('arrayrow_options',$arrayrow_options);
}
```

В шаблоне

```
function add_options(id) {
    var node = document.getElementById(id),
        newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.innerHTML = '<p><select name="nameoptions[]" onChange="showOption_text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"><option value="">Выберите</option>{foreach from=$arrayrow_options item=options}<option value="{$options.id}">{$options.name}</option>{/foreach}</select><span id="seloption_text" style="display:none; float: right; padding-right: 600px;"><select name="textoptions[]" id="option_text"></select></span></p>';
    node.appendChild(newNode);
    return newNode;
}

Параметры товара
<div id="options"></div>
<a href onclick="add_options('options'); return false;"><img src="{$home}/style/{$setup.skin}/images/add_ico.png" alt="image"/>Добавить</a><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Честно пару минут пытался понять суть вопроса. Не вышло. А читать портянку с кодом, чтобы понять в чем вопрос - совсем не хочется, для этого есть Великий и Могучий.

Comment: Есть у нас выпадающий список. Выбираем допустим первое значение, подгружается еще один выпадающий список. Простой пример: выбираем страну, подгружаются города для этой страны. Тут принцип такой же, только я могу добавить несколько значений.

Comment: @vitagame не надо писать отчет сюда "я сделал" если сделали, выложите решение.

Comment: Там слишком много расписывать.

Answer (score 1):

Есть много готовых реализаций динамических выпадающих списков. Краткое гугление показало, например, вот это [вот это](http://www.webpress.uz/Alexandr/jQuery/Kaskadnye-vypadayushchie-spiski-jQuery/#.UZ7yTuvJ1w8) или [вот это](http://www.codeassembly.com/examples/jquerycombo/test.html)